# How to look for all filesystem which start with /filesystem

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

When I do `df -h` I get following output

```
/dev/sda                       3.7T   34M  3.7T   1% /filesystem1
/dev/sdb                        3.7T   34M  3.7T   1% /filesystem2
/dev/sdc                        3.7T   34M  3.7T   1% /filesystem3
```

I am using following command to get this list but it is giving blank

`df -h | grep ^filesystem`

Please help to find correct command

Comment: the line does not start with /filesystem

Comment: `...|grep '/filesystem'`. In the future, please ask such questions on https://superuser.com, and please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: `df -h /filesystem*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command looks for `filesystem` at the beginning of the line. There are two problems with that:

1. The string you're looking for begins with `/filesystem`, not `filesystem`; and
2. it's not at the beginning of the line, it's the last field in the line.

You can use `awk` and get the last field with `$NF`.

```
df -h | awk '$NF ~ /^\/filesystem/'
```